# Does なんて = なんと (いう)?

Tags: meaning, history

I know that なんて is a contraction of なんと, but has it also picked up the いう in its meaning? Because なんて means something, and I feel like 何という, which means "something called" (right?) could have just been reduced to なんて because saying "something" is such a common thing to say. Is this right?

Comment: We have two なんて... ①なんて可愛いんだ！How lovely!--なに(何)+と ②あんたなんて嫌いよ！I hate you!--など(等)+と

Comment: Are you talking about this [なんて(何て)](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/165853/m0u/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6/), or this [なんて(等+と)≒など/なんか](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/165854/m0u/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6/) ??

Answer (score 1):

In informal situations (っ)て can be substituted for と when it's being used as a quoting particle.  As such, [何]{なん}という can become [何]{なん}ていう (or more frequently [何]{なん}てゆう in speech).

Answer (score 0):

なんて is a colloquial variant of など. なんか is another one.