# Difference between なんと and なんて

Tags: nuances

According to [wiktionairy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A8), なんと can be used as an "intensifier" in the following sense:

> Used to intensify an adjective. Carries connotations of surprise or being emotionally moved: what a…; how … it is
>
> なんときれいな月つきだろう。
>
> The moon is gorgeous tonight, isn't it?

But it seems like [なんて can be used in this way as well](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/97528/51280)?

Comment: related: [Does なんて = なんと (いう)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13121/does-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a6-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a8-%e3%81%84%e3%81%86)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both can be used for exclamation. To me なんと is more literary.

> [なんと](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A8/#jn-165873)　 感心・失望などの気持ちを強調して表す。**なんて**。「―美しい花だ」「―愚かな人だ」
>
> [なんて](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6/#jn-165853)　驚いたり、あきれたり、感心したりする気持ちを表す。**なんという**。「―だらしないんだ」「―すばらしい絵だ」

A difference is that なんて can be followed directly by a noun whereas なんと can't. E.g.,

- なんてやつだ *What a guy.* = なんというやつだ
- なんとやつだ would be understood as なんと、やつだ. *Wow, (that's) him*.

Comment: Thanks. Judging by those definitions, they seem identical to me (aside from the grammatical thing you pointed out about なんと being unable to precede a noun)?  RE the grammatical point: do you know why that rule with nouns developed? Is there any general pattern being followed here (say, about contractions that end in て vs と)?

Comment: @George That should be etymology of those particular words, as you guess. なんて derives from なんという (see the dictionary link) and connecting-to-noun in nature and なんと derives from なにと which is (due to と) adverbial in nature.

Comment: Just wanted to then confirm that 「なんとやつだ」, literally speaking, means "with what, is a man".  (Or more idiomatically: "with what!, it's him" or just "what! it's him".

Comment: @George なんと like this is an interjection on its own. It's just "wow" or "oh my".